# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! ICY 200 OK

Tags: php

I can load the URL "http://192.99.170.8:5756/;1" in the browser (e.g., Firefox, Chrome) and also in VLC (with song title info).

But I can not get info (even not connected) using PHP 8.1.2.

e.g., fopen says "**Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! ICY 200 OK**"

```
<?php
$url = 'http://192.99.170.8:5756/;1';

if (!$fp = fopen($url, 'rb')) { // 'r' also failed
    trigger_error("Unable to open URL ($url)", E_USER_ERROR);
}

$meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
fclose($fp);

var_dump($meta);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe the http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration. Check `allow_url_fopen` ?

Comment: @maik lowrey: the URL is not mine (not my server), other URLs usually work - some not; additionally: access via browser works - so it can not be the reasons for (even not on the server)